# Elisp regex to match pattern and slice a string

Tags: elisp, emacs24

```
var myStr = require('ssh2')
```

(or) more generic pattern can be,

```
var * = require('*')
```

the fields other than * are needed as it is....

from a statement like mentioned above, how to extract the word 'ssh2' using elisp regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to extract the result from a string, you can use [`string-match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html) and [`match-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html#Simple-Match-Data):

```
(let ((s "var myStr = require('ssh2')"))
  (if (string-match "'\\([^']+\\)'" s)
      (match-string 1 s)))
```

If you're looking for the result string in a buffer, use [`re-search-forward` or `re-search-backward`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html) instead.

Comment: steve the kind guy, changed the question which was incomplete. since i din't say func call require is mandatory there... again, why is this used - \\([^']+\\.. 2 backward slashes on both sides?

Comment: The inner backslashes are required in the regexp to quote the parentheses used to group the result. Then each of those backslashes is quoted with second backslashes to keep them from being discarded when the regexp is parsed.

Comment: Backslashes are special to both strings and regexps in elisp. `"\\(...\\)"` evaluates to the string `\(...\)` which, as a regexp, denotes the group `...`

Comment: phils. """\(...\) which as a regexp, denotes the group""" do you mean, to make a group in regex, you need to use both backward slashes and parens as delimiters?

Comment: late discovery.... in elisp, the fact is "|", "(" and ")" are all just ordinary characters. If you want alternation you need to escape the vertical bar with a backslash: "\|", ditto with grouping via parenthesis: "\(" and "\)"